# having trouble extracting data from a file, spliting it and storing it into array/arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception, readfile

I have a file that contains information like this:
[image: table of the data]

The number of lines varies. The professor is using other document to test the program.

I want to extract the long name from this file and print it.

Here is what I have:

```
public List<String> extractName(List<String> longName)
{
  Data data = new Data();
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(actualFile);
  longName = new List<String>();
  String line = scan.nextLine();

    if(line.contains("---"))
      {
         while(line != null)
      {
         String[] name = line.split(" +");
         longName.add(name[2]);
      }
     data.setLongName(longName);
   }
  return longName;
}
```

and my `main` method and one other method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //process file
      try{
          File actualFile = new File(args[0]);
          System.out.println("File was processed: true");
         }
      catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                System.out.println("File was processed: false. Re-enter filename.");
                return;
            }
      Data data = new Data();
      printInfo(data); // error occurs here
  }

  public static void printInfo(Data d){
        for(int i = 0; i < longName.size(); i++) //error occurs here
          System.out.println(longName.get(i));

  }
```

and my class, in case anyone needs it:

```
public class Data{

    private List<String> longName;

    public void Data(){}

    public void setLongName(List<String> theLongName){
        longName = theLongName;
    }
    public List<String> getLongName(){
        return longName;
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at project2shm.printInfo(project2shm.java:35)
    at project2shm.main(project2shm.java:18)
```

I am so confused. I labeled where the error occurred in the code. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I am guessing your `printInfo` and `main` method is inside your `Data` class.  On that note, you are passing `Data d` to  `printInfo`  but you are really not using it. You are getting NullPointer because clearly `longName` is NULL. Now assuming `printInfo` and `main` method is inside your `Data` class, better use `d.longName.size()`, and more better wrap it inside NULL checking IF condition. But still you would get NP because your  `d.longName` is still NULL, so you need to make sure that you are instantiating it ..

Comment: Where are you calling `extractName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project2shm.main()` never assigns a value to the `longName` variable used by `project2shm.printInfo()`. That `longName` variable is apparently a static variable in the `project2shm` class.

You did not provide the entire source for `project2shm`, but it either does not initialize `longName`, or assigns `null` to it. In either case, that will cause the NPE that you saw.